# Create object instead of array (JS)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have data, that came from back-end.

I'm handling it in the function like this:

```
getAgentSuggestionById(agentId) {
    this._agentsService.getAgentSuggestionById(agentId).subscribe(result =>{
        this.agent = result.items.map(e => {let obj = {name: e.name, id: e.id};
            return obj;
        });
        debugger;
        this.filteredAgents = [...result.items.map(e => {let obj = {name: e.name, id: e.id};
            return obj;
        })];
    });
}
```

For `this.agent` I need to create an object like this - `{name: e.name, id: e.id}`.

Result will always have only 1 value.

Now it creates an array. How I can create an object?

Comment: Just grab the first object from the array? `this.filteredAgents[0]`? NB: Why do you do the same `.map` twice?

Comment: Either take the first element `[0]` or use `reduce` instead of `map`.

Comment: Or: `this.agent = result.items.map(e => {let obj = {name: e.name, id: e.id};
            return obj;
        })[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If your `result.items` is always an array of a single item (i.e. length of 1), you can simply access it by index and return the nested object directly:

```
getAgentSuggestionById(agentId) {
    this._agentsService.getAgentSuggestionById(agentId).subscribe(result => {
        const agent = result.items[0];
        return {
            name: agent.name,
            id: agent.id
        };
    });
}
```